# How does java.NumberFormat pick up its default values for a locale

Tags: java, number-formatting

Lets say I have the following code:

```
 NumberFormat formatter = DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
  System.out.println(formatter.getMaximumFractionDigits());
  Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
  System.out.println(l.getCountry());
```

This prints 3. and country US

If I change the locale to ("sv", "SE"), it still prints 3. AND SE

I am on a windows machine. If I go through the control panel to look at the region settings and look at 'English US' or 'Swedish Sweden' it shows the "Number of digits after decimal" to be 2 for both these countries.

Where are the defaults being picked by the NumberFormat class? How does it end up with a value of 3 for the fractions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of digits after decimal is 2 when formatting currency, but 3 for other purposes:

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
System.out.println(formatter.getMaximumFractionDigits()); // often 2
```

In OpenJDK 7 the number of digits comes from the currency data for the country. The currency data is stored in binary format in a file called `currency.data` in the `lib` directory where the JDK is installed, so changing the number of digits shown after decimal in Windows preferences has no effect on Java applications. If you change the country though you'll see that `NumberFormat` adapts:

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.JAPAN);
System.out.println(formatter.getMaximumFractionDigits()); // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the value is the Locale and the locale data is located in a jar in your JVM folder %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar